# Rem inserting in sqlplus?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

In SQL Developer i am running this:

```
SPOOL C:\Export15.sql;



select /*insert*/* from Arithmisi ;

SPOOL OFF;
```

the outpout is this:

```
REM INSERTING into Arithmisi
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into "Arithmisi" (ARITHMOS) values ('3263');
Insert into "Arithmisi" (ARITHMOS) values ('3294');
Insert into "Arithmisi" (ARITHMOS) values ('3295');
Insert into "Arithmisi" (ARITHMOS) values ('3296');
Insert into "Arithmisi" (ARITHMOS) values ('3297');
Insert into "Arithmisi" (ARITHMOS) values ('3298');
Insert into "Arithmisi" (ARITHMOS) values ('3299');
Insert into "Arithmisi" (ARITHMOS) values ('3300');
Insert into "Arithmisi" (ARITHMOS) values ('3301');
Insert into "Arithmisi" (ARITHMOS) values ('3302');
Insert into "Arithmisi" (ARITHMOS) values ('3303');
Insert into "Arithmisi" (ARITHMOS) values ('3304');
Insert into "Arithmisi" (ARITHMOS) values ('3305');
```

Then i am running the same command in sql plus but the result is this:

### ARITHMOS

```
  3263                                                                      
  3294                                                                      
  3295                                                                      
  3296                                                                      
  3297                                                                      
  3298                                                                      
  3299                                                                      
  3300                                                                      
  3301                                                                      
  3302                                                                      
  3303
```

### ARITHMOS

```
  3304                                                                      
  3305
```

How can it been written in sql plus to produce the same output as SQL Developer?

Comment: sqlplus doesn't support that.

Comment: ok good to know.thnx

Comment: it can be done with SQLCL.

Comment: Yes, but SQLCL is a new Java-based tool that is emulating and extending what SQL\*Plus can do, incorporating functionality found in SQL Developer - such as that `/* insert */` directive, or the even newer `sqlformat insert` command. [Read more about that here](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/02/a-quick-4-1-trick-set-sqlformat/).

Comment: my goal is to save my database values and table parameters from a java program.thnx for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like alex helped with the final goal, but I will take a stab at answering the question you asked. You can get the inserts from sqlplus by forming the inserts as part of the select, but it is a bit tedious.

For one column table:

```
select 'insert into TABLE_NAME values ('''||FIELD_NAME||'''); ' from TABLE_NAME;
```

For multiple columns:

```
select 'insert into TABLE_NAME values ('''
||FIELD1_NAME||''','''                
||FIELD2_NAME||''','''              
||FIELD3_NAME||'''); ' 
from TABLE_NAME;
```

In your case:

```
SPOOL C:\Export15.sql;
select 'insert into Arithmisi values ('''||ARITHMOS||'''); ' from Arithmisi;
SPOOL OFF;
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: @asd32 I haven't had this installed in my work environments. I might fight for it now, pretty cool stuff!